# Why doesn't buttonName.removeFromSuperview always remove the button?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my swift game, we have a main game scene and then once you die in the game, it puts you on an endgame screen where your score is displayed. From this screen, the user then has the option to tap a button to change the scene back to the game. Most of the time, the button is removed and everything works normally but every so often it doesn't remove it and overlays itself over the game scene. This is the code ran by the button-

```
        scoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        highLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        RestartBtn.removeFromSuperview()
        self.RestartBtn.removeFromSuperview()
        self.highLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        self.menuButton.removeFromSuperview()
        self.scoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        self.scene!.view?.presentScene(GameplayScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.8))
```

Comment: Any difference between `**Btn` & `self.**Btn` ?

Comment: Just something we tried to fix the issue.

Comment: If `removeFromSuperview` is definitely being called on the button, I would then check to make sure you're not adding the button back to its superview at some point.

Comment: I just checked, it doesn't look like its being added back anywhere.

Comment: Unrelated: much risk here `self.scene!.view?`. That is what `if let`, `as?` and `guard` are for.

Comment: Why `RestartBtn.removeFromSuperview()` and `self.RestartBtn.removeFromSuperview()`? Are you possibly hiding class variables in your local scope?

Comment: Solution below not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

`self.menuButton` and all the others are probably `weak` references.
i.e., they become stale once the view has been removed from superview. It sometimes work, sometimes doesn't to the whim of how it is referenced in `self.menuButton = <something>`, which, if done in `loadView` or `viewDidLoad`, is just plain dangerous.

**Different approach**

I would recommend not juggling with the UI so much, and adopt a more constant referencing technique, such as `hidden`, or `alpha = 0`.

```swift
self.menuButton.removeFromSuperview()
// self.menuButton is stale. You can't re-add your button from that reference
```

**Animate show/hide views**

This will not destroy your references, and look oh so much better than `removeFromSuperview`:

```swift
// Hide with animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:.4f animations:^{
    [self.menuButton setAlpha:0]; // Hide with animation
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // If you decide to remove the view permanently, do it here
    // Without knowing more, I wouldn't recommend it
}];
```

You can then show the UI again, with or without animation:

```swift
[self.menuButton setAlpha:1]; // Show without animation
```

Comment: Could you just provide an example? I'm relatively new to this. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Added a block that will fade out a view in 0.4 seconds, which you could later on fade back in.